# ASP.Net Core MVC Bootstrap 4 Modal Form Submit Not Working

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm writing a ASP.Net Core 2.2 application, trying unsuccessfully to implement a Bootstrap 4 modal view to confirm the deletion of records from a database/table view.

Each row of the table has a delete button.  When the delete button for a given row in the table is clicked, the modal delete confirmation box appears as expected.  When the user click on the button to confirm the deletion of the record, the modal delete confirmation box disappears, and nothing happens.

Here is the Razor code that generates the rows in the table:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (LearningObjective item in Model.LearningObjectives)
        {
         <tr>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Sentence)</td>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Verbs)</td>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Measurables)</td>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Blooms)</td>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Levels)</td>
             @if (ViewBag.Title == "Build and Analyze Learning Objectives")
                 {
                  <td>
                      <a id="deleteCustomerModal"
                      data-toggle="modal"
                      asp-action="DeleteLearningObjective"
                      asp-route-id="@item.Id"
                      data-target="#modal-delete"
                      class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                      Delete
                       </a>
                    </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
</tbody>
```

Here is an example of how the code above renders an actual table row (from the page source):

```
<tr>
    <td>analyze all the fun things we can do with this app</td>
    <td>Analyze, Do</td>
    <td>Yes, No</td>
    <td>Yes, No</td>
    <td>4, -</td>
    <td>
         <a id="deleteCustomerModal" 
          data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#modal-delete" 
          class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" 
          href="/Home/DeleteLearningObjective/296">
          <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
          Delete
          </a>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

That href above is correct.

Here is the HTML for the modal form:

```
<form asp-action="DeleteLearningObjective" role="form"><
    <div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalDeleteLabel">Delete Learning Objective</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body form-horizontal">
                    Are you sure you want to delete this learning objective?
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="modalDeleteButton">Delete</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    // boostrap 4 load modal example from docs
    $('#modal-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
        var url = button.attr("href");
        var modal = $(this);
        // note that this will replace the content of modal-content everytime the modal is opened
        modal.find('.modal-content').load(url);
    });

    $('#modal-delete').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        // remove the bs.modal data attribute from it
        $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
        // and empty the modal-content element
        $('#modal-delete .modal-content').empty();
    });
});
```

Stepping through:

*Table rows are rendered correctly, and each rows href value is correct.

*The modal appears as expected.

*When the modals Delete button is clicked, the jQuery code executes. The code successfully finds and extracts the correct href value from the table row.

*The last line of the jQuery code (modal.find('.modal-content').load(url);) executes, but I do see the following type of error in Chrome's Debug console:

GET https://localhost:44389/Home/DeleteLearningObjective/296 405

*The modal closes

So, the href value from the table row never actually gets passed to the modal.  I suspect that is because it is being interpreted as a GET request rather than a POST request (per the error).

I've been Googling and trying to solve this for two days and I am about to take a hammer to my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following modification :

1.In `<a>Delete</a>` ,remove `asp-action` and `asp-route-id`,then add the `data-id` in order to send the id of delete-item to the controller

```
<a id="deleteCustomerModal"
    data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#modal-delete"
    data-id="@item.Id"
    class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    Delete
 </a>
```

2.Add `id="myForm"` to the form , and add the hidden input which is used to get the id of the deleted item in the `modal-body` section

```
<form asp-action="DeleteLearningObjective" role="form" id="myForm">
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalDeleteLabel">Delete Learning Objective</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="     form-horizontal">
                Are you sure you want to delete this learning objective?
                <input hidden name="id"/>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="modalDeleteButton">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

3. Javascript

   ```
   <script>
   $(function () {
       $('#modal-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
           var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
           var id = button.data("id");
           var modal = $(this);

           modal.find('.modal-content input').val(id);
       });

       $("#modalDeleteButton").click(function () {
           $("#myForm").submit();

       });

   });
   ```
4. Result:
   [image]